# How to test FileReader using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, filereader

I am trying to get 100% coverage in my test and it this one passes but then it still highlights  the render.onload function

Component.jsx:

```
handleInputChange = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const { target } = evt;
  let value;
  let self = this;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (evt) {
    self.setState({
      previewPicture: evt.target.result,
      error: null
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(target.files[0]);
  value = target.files[0];          
  const name = target.name;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
};
```

Test:

```
    const evt = {
      target: {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'profilePicture',
        files: [{ name: 'testName' }]
      },
      preventDefault: jest.fn()
    };
    const component = mount(<Component {...props} />).instance();
    evt.target.files[0] = new Blob([evt.target.files[0]], {type : 'img/png'});
    component.handleInputChange(evt);
    expect(component.state.profilePicture).toEqual(file);
});
```

I want to have all covered in the test but I dont know test the FileRader

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to test other component's behavior in the scope of your component.

So, if you are developing a component that uses `FileReader()` you must assume that `FileReader()` is working properly. `FileReader()` must have it own tests to guarantee that its behavior is also working well, this way we keep the responsability of each component in the scope of its implementation.